# Navicat message - out of memory

Tags: mysql, mariadb, navicat

i have table with about 4 million rows, and each rows consist of 30 columns. It should every day to table become bigger and bigger with new rows.

When i want to see all data in navicat browser on 2.5 million it gives me message out of memory, in my opinion, it has nothing to do with server resources?

Also, i tried right click on connection -> Execute sql file, it runs succesfull, but it does not show data.

Comment: Another example of a 3rd party tool getting in the way?

Comment: @RickJames sry, but i don't understand your question?

Comment: _Probably_ using the "mysql" commandline tool would not have this problem.  Navicat and other 3rd party packages between applications and MySQL tend to have limitations that don't show up until you stress them.  Fetching 4M rows is a stress.

Answer (score 1):

You have a large table. When you try to retrieve the whole contents of the table as a result set, it seems your client software (Navicat) can't get enough RAM to hold it.

The *entire purpose* of SQL is to allow the handling of very large tables: specifically tables that don't fit in RAM. So, it doesn't make sense to pull your whole table into a client.

If you *must* retrieve the whole table for some reason, try the `mysqldump` command line file, and put it into a file.

You may wish to use the `LIMIT 1000` clause or some such thing at the end of your queries from the client program.

Comment: i want to read all data in Navicat, if i use LIMIT1milion, or LIMIT 1000 OFFSET 1000 , this does not solve problem in client Navicat because you will always see same result, you cant walk througt next 1000 rows. With queries it works normal, only i can't load in browser all data

Comment: You're saying "I need to carry fourteen tonnes of coal in my pickup truck. But whenever I load the coal into the truck the tires burst. Can you tell my what kind of tires won't burst?"  Look, you are trying to put a very large result set into a medium sized program. You Can't Do That.

Comment: What is the purpose building app if you don't know what quality of data is? what is the purpose of duing physical work and getting back 500k by 500k ..? there must have some normal way to see all data, and way to see how i can and what i need to normalize of data